# long int array causing error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, compiler-errors

I am aware of other questions to this error message but none of them solves the error message in my case 
the code here finds the the value of the first triangle number to have over N divisors where N is input (this problem is typically found on project Euler) I use [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to generate a list of prime numbers and which is used by the [Divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)
and I cached the values of the triangular numbers for N = 500->1000 
to save time. and upon compiling on GCC I found this error message

```
 error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
 if(n>=500) printf("%li\n",tri[n-500]);
                              ^
```

here is the full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000000
#define NofPrime 78498
int main(){
  long tri[]  = {76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,76576500,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,103672800,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,236215980,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320,842161320};
  unsigned char *table = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
  int i,j,c=0;
  unsigned int *prime = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*NofPrime);
  for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)table[i] = 0;
  for(i=2;i<MAX;i++){
  if(table[i]==0){
   prime[c] = i;
   c++;
   for(j=2;i*j<MAX;j++) table[i*j] = 1;
  }}
  free(table);
  int t;
  scanf("%i",&t);
  while(t>0){
   unsigned long max=1,counter,tri,n,tricpy;
    scanf("%li",&n);
    if(n>=500) printf("%li\n",tri[n-500]);
    else  while(max++){
      tri = (1+max)*max/2;
      tricpy = tri;
      counter=1;
      int i,j;
      for(i=0;prime[i] <= tricpy;i++){
        j =1;
        while(tricpy%prime[i]==0){
          j++;
          tricpy/=prime[i];
        }
        counter*=j;
      }
      if(counter>n){
        printf("%lu,",tri);
        break;
      }
    }
    t--;
  }
  free(prime);
}
```

Comment: You have redeclared `tri` just inside the `while` loop: `unsigned long max=1,counter,tri,n,tricpy;`

Comment: oh I didn't notice that at all 
I went on looking for array overflows and that sort of things !!
thank you

Comment: Indent your code more generously, 4 spaces is considered more readable.  Wrap long lines at 79 characters, the definition of `long tri[] = {...};` is a real pain.

Comment: so how to define an array like this one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of tri in

```
unsigned long max=1,counter,tri,n,tricpy;
```

will be the one used in

```
if(n>=500) printf("%li\n",tri[n-500]);
```

and so indeed tri is not an array or pointer.